# What is the connectivity of symmetric (topological) join

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a CW complex. Denote by $*^{n}X$ the topological join of $X$ done $n-$times in the sense of Milnor, i.e., $*^{n}X = \left\{t_{1}x_{1} \oplus t_{2}x_{2} \oplus \cdots \oplus t_{n}x_{n} : \sum_{i=1}^{n} t_{i} = 1, t_{i} \geq 0, x_{i} \in X \right\}$. Milnor proves in *Construction of Universal bundles II (1955)* as Lemma 2.3 that if $X$ is $(k-1)-$connected, then the $n-$fold join $*^{n}X$ is $(nk+n-2)-$connected. Let $(*^{n})X$ denote the quotient of $*^{n}X$ with the symmetric group $S_n$, i.e., let $(*^{n})X = *^{n}X / S_{n}$, called as the symmetric $n-$fold join of $X$. I wish to know what can we say about the connectivity of $(*^{n})X$. In particular, **can we say that similar to the case of the usual join, the connectivity of the symmetric join $(*^{n})X$ also increases with $n$?**

Using Milnor’s above paper’s Lemma 2.2, one can show that $(*^{n})X$ is simply connected for any $n$, but I am interested in better (stronger) connectivity results about $(*^{n})X$ in terms of $n$, if possible.